# Trying to grab a json file to cache it locally

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
<?php
$json_url = 'https://api.feedbin.me/v2/entries.json';

$username = 'username';  // authentication
$password = 'password';  // authentication

$ch = curl_init( $json_url );

$options = array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_USERPWD => $username . ":" . $password   // authentication
);

// Setting curl options
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting JSON result string

$cache_feedbin = '/BLAH/'.sha1($result).'.json';

    if(file_exists($cache_feedbin) && filemtime($cache_feedbin) > time() - 1000){
        // if a cache file newer than 1000 seconds exist, use it
        $data_feedbin = file_get_contents($cache_feedbin);
    } else {
        $data_feedbin = file_get_contents($result);
        file_put_contents($cache_feedbin,json_encode($data_feedbin));
    }

    foreach (array_slice(json_decode($data_feedbin), 0, 5) as $obj) {
        $feedbin_title = $obj->title;
        $feedbin_url = $obj->url;
        echo '<li><a href="', $feedbin_url, '">', $feedbin_title, '</a></li>';
    }
?>
```

Why I'm getting "false" in the locally cached json? Is that json_encode wrong?

Comment: Have you checked for a curl error? Look at the output of curl_error($ch) to see what it reports.

Comment: It works without the caching mechanism (if I just do json_decode($result) ). So seems something wrong with $cache_feedbin

Comment: I'm confused about a number of things here. Is your goal to cache the JSON document you're fetching from feedbin? If so, it's pointless because you have to fetch it in order to calculate the cache filename. Later, you're treating the return value from the curl operation as a filename (passing it to file_get_contents), when it appears to be a JSON document. You may additionally be double-encoding JSON, by calling json_encode on what is already JSON data (though it's not clear). If you could describe your goals, it would be easier to answer.

Comment: Eheh, sorry! :P
I'm trying to store the json file locally, so when json_decode is called it needs to decode the local file, not the remote one. And it works like that if the local file isn't older than 1000 seconds (if so, the local file gets updated re-fetching remote one).

Comment: OK -- what is the goal of this caching, i.e. why not just parse the remote document once you've fetched it anyway? And the other questions?

Comment: Because I should fetch the remote document (which contains 100 entries) EVERY time a user visit the page (and calls the function). With caching I need to fetch the remote document once (so it's faster and has less impact on CPU).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31358/discussion-between-asmecher-and-multiformeingegno)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling certificate validation in your curl options:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

You can check for specifics on curl errors by looking at:

```
curl_error($ch)
```

...which will probably report a certificate validation problem.

Comment: Uhm, but if I just do 

`$result =  curl_exec($ch); // Getting JSON result string

 foreach (array_slice(json_decode($result), 0, 5) as $obj) {
  $feedbin_title = $obj->title;
  $feedbin_url = $obj->url;
  echo '<li><a href="', $feedbin_url, '">', $feedbin_title, '</a></li>';
 }`

it works. So it's a problem with the cache thing ($cache_feedbin, file_put_contents, etc)